# Remove a fixed pattern from filenames in a directory

Tags: linux, shell

i have many file names as below

create_to_abc.txt

create_to_info.txt

create_to_pass.txt

create_to_user_pass.ext

and want to remove **create_to_** from the above file names so it should looks like

abc.txt

info.txt

pass.txt

user_pass.ext

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

use `mmv` to rename multiple files.

```
mmv -m "create_to_*" "#1"
```